# Remove leading 0 from specific field

Tags: bash, sed, awk, string

I have a file with multiple fields but only want to remove the leading 0s from the 2nd column (col B) rather than all of the columns. I have tried: `sed 's/^0//g' filename > new_filename` but this does not work.

**EXAMPLE DATA:**

```
A B C D E
2 02 56 0.987 0.332
1 09 67 0.567 0.243
9 06 37 0.523 0.263
0 10 47 0.378 0.875
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT:**

```
A B C D E
2 2 56 0.987 0.332
1 9 67 0.567 0.243
9 6 37 0.523 0.263
0 10 47 0.378 0.875
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will chose `awk` for this task:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 {$2 = sprintf("%d", $2)};1' <file
```

or:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 {$2 += 0};1' <file
```

or:

```
awk '{sub(/^0+/, "", $2)};1' <file
```

Comment: Could also do `{$2 += 0}`

Comment: @glennjackman: Good point, added it.

Comment: While `$2 += 0` is shorter, I find `sub(/^0+/, "", $2)` clearer.

Comment: @Gilles: Fair point. Added it.